# Oracle 11g - Find Records in a CLOB with Carriage Return Line Feed

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am on Oracle 11g. I am trying to do a Find and Replace functionality on a CLOB field (using REPLACE).

Now the data in my CLOB has CRLFs in them, the replace works just fine until I want to find a string that contains CRLFs. Perhaps this would be best explained by example:

```
So say the text in my field is:
----------------------------------
Hi there this is some text
that has CRLFS in it.
Some other text that
is there also.
Have a nice day
```

Now what I want to do is replace all occurrences of this INCLUDING the CRLFs:

```
Search Text
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Some other text that
is there also.
```

With this text INCLUING the CRLFs:

```
Replace Text
------------------------------------
Some other text that
has some new text that is there also.
```

So That could come out to be:

```
 ----------------------------------
 Hi there this is some text
 that has CRLFS in it.
 Some other text that
 has some new text that is there also.
 Have a nice day
```

Now I am doing this in a stored procedure and the Search Text and Replace Text come in as variables, but When I try and say where like % || ReplaceText || '%' it returns 0 rows.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Here is my stored procedure (iOldResponsibilities is the Search Text, iNewResponsibilities is the replace text:

```
PROCEDURE FindReplaceResponsibilities (
    iOldResponsibilities    IN  JP_JOB_FAMILIES.RESPONSIBILITIES%TYPE,
    iNewResponsibilities    IN  JP_JOB_FAMILIES.RESPONSIBILITIES%TYPE,
    oNumRowsUpdated         OUT INTEGER
)
IS

  BEGIN
        oNumRowsUpdated := 0;


        SAVEPOINT sp_jf_findrepresp;

        -- If there is no old text to search for then, 
        -- append the new text to the end of every row.
        -- Else replace all occurrences of the old text with the new text
        IF iOldResponsibilities IS NULL THEN
          UPDATE JP_JOB_FAMILIES
            SET RESPONSIBILITIES = RESPONSIBILITIES || iNewResponsibilities;

          oNumRowsUpdated := SQL%ROWCOUNT;

        ELSE
          UPDATE JP_JOB_FAMILIES
            SET RESPONSIBILITIES = REPLACE(RESPONSIBILITIES, iOldResponsibilities, iNewResponsibilities)
          WHERE RESPONSIBILITIES like '%' || iOldResponsibilities || '%';

          -- I have also tried this:
          --WHERE dbms_lob.instr(RESPONSIBILITIES, TO_CLOB(iOldResponsibilities)) > 0; -- This is a LIKE for CLOBS

          oNumRowsUpdated := SQL%ROWCOUNT;

        END IF;

        RETURN;

        EXCEPTION

            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                BEGIN
                    oNumRowsUpdated := -1;
                    ROLLBACK TO sp_jf_findrepresp;
                    dbms_output.put_line('error: ' || sqlerrm);
                    RETURN;
                END;

END FindReplaceResponsibilities;
```

The Text is coming from an asp.net application (c#) as String values:

```
 public int FindReplaceJobFamilyResponsibilities(String oldResponsibilities, String newResponsibilities, IDbTransaction transaction = null)
    {
        using (IDbCommand cmd = this._dataHelper.GetStoredProcedure(_connectionString,
            "JP_JOBFAM_PKG.FindReplaceResponsibilities", true))
        {
            _dataHelper.SetParameterValue(cmd, "iOldResponsibilities", oldResponsibilities);
            _dataHelper.SetParameterValue(cmd, "iNewResponsibilities", newResponsibilities);
            DataHelperBase.VerifyParameters(cmd.Parameters, false);
            base.SetExecuteConnection(cmd, transaction);
            _dataHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);

            return Convert.ToInt32(_dataHelper.GetParameterValue(cmd, "oNumRowsUpdated"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Normally crlf shouldn't be a problem. Two things I can think of: One of the lines has an extra space before the crlf, which is easily overlooked. Or, maybe one of the values has only cr or only lf instead of crlf.

Comment: That's my thoughts also. Just to be safe though, I copied and pasted the original text from the field I want to search to avoid that.

Comment: That sounds safe, but if you copy Linux text (lf only), and paste it somewhere in Windows, chances are it will magically insert the crs for you.. To rule this out, I would inspect a hex dump of that field first because blindly debigging this code.

Comment: Ok i'll try checking that out. The code is windows to windows

Comment: How are you generating the `iOldResponsibilities` you pass in - are you sure that does have both CR and LF (as `chr(10)` and `chr(13)`) and it isn't being mangled somewhere? Might be worth dumping that from within the procedure too.

Comment: Those are coming from an asp.NET web app (c#) on the application they come in as String values. I'll update the post to reflect

Comment: Also I tried to remove the where clause all together and allow the replace to just run through all the records. It did pull all records in the DB, but it didn't replace any occurrences of the old text when CRLFs were included in the old text string.

Comment: You still haven't said how (or if) you've verified that `iOldRespnsibilities` does actually contain what you think when it reaches the procedure, or even when you call it. It sounds like it's losing the CRLF somewhere, if it ever had it.

Comment: Yeah I think that's the problem, I need to figure out how to verify that. I tried calling the Stored Proc in SQL Developer and it works fine. When I debug my app code in Visual Studio, I see the string values do contain the CRLFs. Then question I need to look at now is are those lost in the actual call to the DB? I'll let you know what I find.

Comment: So what I did was I created a table for testing, and in my stored proc I stored the values fromt the parameters in there. Then after calling I selected from the table and I see my values in there just fine, yet they failed to update.

Comment: Also, I tried the path where I leave iOldResponsiblities NULL so it appends. I inserted text with CRLFs in iNewResponsiblities and that worked great.

Comment: And tried leaving iNewResponsiblities NULL so it deletes, and that works. It only seems to be a problem when both Old and New have values with CRLFS in them.

Comment: Hey Alex, Thanks, I figured out how to get a hex dump, and I think I have a data problem. The data in my production db has CRLFs but in my Test DB its only LFs. I think that is what is causing me greif.

Comment: Confirmed, bad data GIGO! Looks like I'm too new to answer my own question, so this comment will have to do.

Thanks again Alex

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to be a case of bad data. The data in my Test DB was corrupted and only had LFs instead of CRLFs.

GIGO :-)

Thanks for all your help

Oh and by the way In my code example I went with the INSTR function instead of the like function. If the user entered a % in the text to search through that might have messed up the like statement. (Can't filter those out because % might be a valid character in my data)

Here is the Final Code:

```
PROCEDURE FindReplaceResponsibilities (
iOldResponsibilities    IN  JP_JOB_FAMILIES.RESPONSIBILITIES%TYPE,
iNewResponsibilities    IN  JP_JOB_FAMILIES.RESPONSIBILITIES%TYPE,
oNumRowsUpdated         OUT INTEGER
```

)
IS

BEGIN
        oNumRowsUpdated := 0;

```
    SAVEPOINT sp_jf_findrepresp;

    -- If there is no old text to search for then, 
    -- append the new text to the end of every row.
    -- Else replace all occurrences of the old text with the new text
    IF iOldResponsibilities IS NULL THEN
      UPDATE JP_JOB_FAMILIES
        SET RESPONSIBILITIES = RESPONSIBILITIES || iNewResponsibilities;

      oNumRowsUpdated := SQL%ROWCOUNT;

    ELSE
      UPDATE JP_JOB_FAMILIES
        SET RESPONSIBILITIES = REPLACE(RESPONSIBILITIES, iOldResponsibilities, iNewResponsibilities)
      WHERE dbms_lob.instr(RESPONSIBILITIES, iOldResponsibilities) > 0; 

      oNumRowsUpdated := SQL%ROWCOUNT;

    END IF;

    RETURN;

    EXCEPTION

        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            BEGIN
                oNumRowsUpdated := -1;
                ROLLBACK TO sp_jf_findrepresp;
                dbms_output.put_line('error: ' || sqlerrm);
                RETURN;
            END;
```

END FindReplaceResponsibilities;

The code from my application was fine:

```
public int FindReplaceJobFamilyResponsibilities(String oldResponsibilities, String newResponsibilities, IDbTransaction transaction = null)
{
    using (IDbCommand cmd = this._dataHelper.GetStoredProcedure(_connectionString,
        "JP_JOBFAM_PKG.FindReplaceResponsibilities", true))
    {
        _dataHelper.SetParameterValue(cmd, "iOldResponsibilities", oldResponsibilities);
        _dataHelper.SetParameterValue(cmd, "iNewResponsibilities", newResponsibilities);
        DataHelperBase.VerifyParameters(cmd.Parameters, false);
        base.SetExecuteConnection(cmd, transaction);
        _dataHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);

        return Convert.ToInt32(_dataHelper.GetParameterValue(cmd, "oNumRowsUpdated"));
    }
}
```